# Spoof texting a regiatered number to yourself and relying....having a conversation

Tags: spoofing, sms

I feel like I am going crazy. A friend was at my house and received text messages from a number from a person i know. She had a conversation with this number for basically a week. She is now saying that she set it up to make it look like it was that person texting her. The messages were even coming in when she was asleep.. Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely possible; your friend most likely set up a bot to reply to her when she said certain things, in order to simulate a conversation. Tell your friend nice prank :D

Comment: Thanks for replying....however, when this number messaged her back, it was not a generic response...it was very tailored to this exact time and situation that was happening....like it did not seem like an automatic reaponse

Comment: @AbbsCP It does not have to be a generic response. Imagine you set a bot to do this: when it receives one message, it replies "I am doing well", when it receives a second message, it says "I have been spending time with my family", when it receives a third message, it messages "Good-bye!" Then, your friend texts the bot, and asks "How are you?", "What have you been doing lately?", and "Hope you have a nice day!" the conversation seems natural.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you are saying.  Its just weird because it gave specific info and a street name in the texts.  Thanks for your help!